# How can I get the absolute time from a string like '5 hours ago'?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have data set, say date = ['5 minutes ago ', '5 hours ago ', '6 seconds ago '], I want to make another list with exact time like if it was 5 minutes ago at 12:55, I want that to show 12:50 in the other list say abs_time

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? What went wrong?

Comment: You would have to use some custom setup I assume. There are packages which can parse certain human readable time strings [see pytimeparse](https://pypi.org/project/pytimeparse/). You could then treat the `ago` separately and add this functionality yourself.

Comment: I have tried some methods, all are resulting in error or doesn't do nothing to the output

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [lib](https://pypi.org/project/Chronyk/) that can do that for you

```
from chronyk import Chronyk

expressions = ['5 minutes ago ', '5 hours ago ', '6 seconds ago ']

for expression in expressions:  
  t = Chronyk(expression)
  print(f'{expression} --> {t.ctime()}')
```

output

```
5 minutes ago  --> Mon Sep 27 11:00:16 2021
5 hours ago  --> Mon Sep 27 06:05:16 2021
6 seconds ago  --> Mon Sep 27 11:05:10 2021
```